# Complete query with missing months and regions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mm, inv.invoicedate) as [month],
    SUM(amount) AS amount,  
    inv.[state]
FROM 
    invoice inv
WHERE 
    inv.[state] IN ('TX','AZ','NV')
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm, inv.invoicedate), inv.[state]
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(mm, inv.invoicedate)
```

This query result is the following:

[image]

We only have 3 states in the DB: TX, AZ and NV.

What I need is no matter if the data only returns 4 months I need to complete all the year months and regions. For the missing months the amount of course will be 0.

For example in the above results, April just have data for TX and NV, I will need to have data for AZ with Amount 0 so every month has 3 rows. So the total rows that I have to get are 36 that is 3 regions times 12 months.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`VALUES` clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate derived tables of all the `month` and `state` values of interest, then `LEFT JOIN` to the invoice table and `GROUP BY` the month and state, using `COALESCE` to turn `NULL` values into 0:

```
SELECT months.month, 
       states.state, 
       COALESCE(SUM(inv.amount), 0) AS amount
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS months(month)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('AZ'), ('NV'), ('TX')) AS states(state)
LEFT JOIN invoice inv ON DATEPART(mm, inv.invoicedate) = months.month
                     AND inv.state = states.state
GROUP BY months.month, states.state
ORDER BY months.month, states.state
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0eb08c18578f17d6ed88e4f06c6cc27)